# "Half of its" or "Half its"

Tags: grammar

I couldn't seem to find anyone asking a question like this anywhere, so I figured I'd start here. The sentence in question is

> "A dolphin sleeps with **half its** brain awake so it can remain aware of
>   its underwater environment."

My question is would it be more grammatically correct to say "**half of its**" or is "**half its**" just as valid a way to write this sentence as "half of its"? Whatever the answer, is there anyone that may have a rule or some form of logical explanation as to why that answer is correct?

I appreciate any help that can be offered.

Comment: Both are commonly used and sound fine.

Comment: I thought so, but I was looking more for an explanation as to the "why".

Comment: Your question has been asked before. Try this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217600/should-i-use-half-the-time-or-half-of-the-time

Comment: "*half of its" or is "half its*"++ The meaning is the same but the structures are different. In "half its brain" is the head word is brain = noun; its brain is a noun phrase and "half" is a noun acting as an adjective - but it is not classed as an adjective: ++ Determiners precede nouns. In "half the time," both **half** and **its** function as determiners, but because **half** must come before **its**, half is a "predeterminer". Half its brain is itself a noun phrase. ++ In half of its brain, "half" (a noun) is the head word; and is modified by the prepositional phrase "of its brain".

Comment: Thanks Isabel Archer and Greybeard. I guess the answer isn't super 'cut and dry' and is more a matter of how you want to write.